# Drawing multiple circles with text in them using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

I am a new javascript programmer. I am trying to make a visualization that draws circles based on categories ("basically a single category on every circle"). My issue is that my code only prints one circle, with all categories on top of each other.

```
 <script> 
        var width = 600;
        var height = 600;

        var data = d3.json("/data", function(error, data){
                    console.log(data)
        // Make SVG container 
        var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
                             .append("svg")
                             .attr("width", width)
                             .attr("height", height);

        var elem = svgContainer.selectAll("div")
                               .data(data);

        var elemEnter = elem.enter()
                            .append("g")

        var circles = elemEnter.append("circle")
                              .attr("cx", 100)
                              .attr("cy", 100)
                              .attr("r",80)
                              .style("fill", "blue")

        elemEnter.append("text")
                 .attr("dy", function(d){
            return d.SkillProficiencyId +80;
            }).attr("dx",function(d){ return d.SkillProficiencyId-1;})
                    .text(function(d){return d.CategoryName});
        });


    </script>
```

[image]

```
> Sample of my Data
(18) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
EmployeeId: 11111
AdUserName: null
FirstName: "ABC"
LastName: "DEF"
SkillId: 2346
CategoryName: "Adaptive Security Architecture"
SkillProficiencyId: 1
SkillProficiencyLevel: "Beginner"
__proto__: Object
1: {EmployeeId: 11111, AdUserName: null, FirstNam...
2: {EmployeeId: 11111, AdUserName: null, FirstName....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a example with circles dynamically created, with text centered inside.

https://codepen.io/mayconmesquita/pen/OJyRZxX

**Demo:**

[image]

**The JS code:** [Edited *]

```
var width = 600;
var height = 600;

// Place your JSON here.
var data = [
  { CategoryName: 'Adaptive Security', SkillProficiencyId: 1 },
  { CategoryName: 'Programmer', SkillProficiencyId: 2 },
  { CategoryName: 'Coffee Drinker', SkillProficiencyId: 3 }
];

/*
  This 'cxBase' will be multiplied by element's index, and sum with offset.
  So for 3 elements, cx = 0, 200, 400 ...
  All these values changeable by this vars.
*/
const cxBase = 200;
const cxOffset = 100;

console.log(data);

// Make SVG container  
var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

// This function will iterate your data
data.map(function(props, index) {
  var cx = cxBase * (index) + cxOffset; // Here CX is calculated

  var elem = svgContainer.selectAll("div").data(data);

  var elemEnter = elem.enter()
  .append("g")

  var circles = elemEnter.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", cx)
  .attr("cy", 100)
  .attr("r", 80)
  .style("fill", "blue");

  elemEnter
  .append("text")
  .style("fill", "white")
  .attr("dy", function(d){
    return 105;
  })
  .attr("dx",function(d){
    return cx - (props.CategoryName.length * 3.5);
  })
  .text(function (d) {
    return props.CategoryName
  });
});
```

**Edit:**

1. As author requested, i did improve the code. Now the circle's cx coordinate is calculated dynamically based on array element's index.

```
/*
  This 'cxBase' will be multiplied by element's index, and sum with offset
  So for 3 elements, cx = 0, 200, 400 ...
  All these values changeable by this vars.
*/
const cxBase = 200;
const cxOffset = 100;
```

Comment: works great, thank you! Two quick questions, my json data does not include cx values. So I created `var = props.SkillProficiencyId * 100` and I can still print individual circles/text but now they overlap I noticed that some circles will have the same cx (since the SkillProficiency might repeat). How can I make sure each circle prints and does not overlap? And I also noticed that the text can be too long and is not completely visible @Maycon Mesquita

Comment: Hi @jessgtrz! You're welcome! I edited the answer and codpen. I added a way to calc cx dynamically, based on element's index, so that, you no more need to include cx on your json. :) Check there!

Comment: awesome! I was looking into d3plus' wrapped method to adjust the text but your function also takes care of it. This is really great! Another question, and I make a new question if it works better for you since my initial question has been technically solved already. Let me know! To take care of the window sizing in parallel with the # of circles that show, I'm looking into `var svg = d3.select("div#container")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 300 300")
  .classed("svg-content", true);` @Maycon Mesquita

Comment: my thinking behind using SkillProficiencyId within the circle size value was because the circles need to be of different size depending on the SkillProficiencyId (which equate to 1,2,3,4 or 5). I would like to have the circles' be of different size @Maycon Mesquita

Comment: I'm glad you liked. So, please mark this answer as solved, open another question and send me the link. I can help you again, this will be easy. =)

Comment: thanks again! new question is [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61349568/adjusting-circle-size-and-svg-size)