# Adjusting circle size text and svg size

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am a new javascript programmer. I'm trying to adjust the circles' size and svg size given the size of the window. Also, the code now creates circles of different sizes, but haven't been able to simultaneously adjust to the text size.

```
var width = 600;
var height = 600;

// Place your JSON here.
var data = [
  { CategoryName: 'Adaptive Security', SkillProficiencyId: 1 },
  { CategoryName: 'Programmer', SkillProficiencyId: 2 },
  { CategoryName: 'Coffee Drinker', SkillProficiencyId: 3 }
];

/*
  This 'cxBase' will be multiplied by element's index, and sum with offset.
  So for 3 elements, cx = 0, 200, 400 ...
  All these values changeable by this vars.
*/
const cxBase = 200;
const cxOffset = 100;

console.log(data);

// Make SVG container  
var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

// This function will iterate your data
data.map(function(props, index) {
  var cx = cxBase * (index) + cxOffset; // Here CX is calculated

  var elem = svgContainer.selectAll("div").data(data);

  var elemEnter = elem.enter()
  .append("g")

  var circles = elemEnter.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", cx)
  .attr("cy", 100)
  .attr("r", props.SkillProficiencyId * 20)
  .style("fill", "blue");

  elemEnter
  .append("text")
  .style("fill", "white")
  .attr("dy", function(d){
    return 105;
  })
  .attr("dx",function(d){
    return cx - (props.CategoryName.length * 3.5);
  })
  .text(function (d) {
    return props.CategoryName
  });
});
```

[image]

**Using `.attr("viewBox", "0 0 680 490")` doesn't work so far. Just makes all the circles bigger but not in proportion to the window**

```
    // Make SVG container  
    var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 680 490")
    .attr("presserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
    //.attr("height", height)
    ;
```

[image]

Comment: instead of an svg element with width and height use a viewBox attribute

Comment: @enxaneta,I tried adding this to my  `.attr("viewBox", "0 0 680 490")
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")` to my ` var svgContainer = d3.select("body")` but it's didn't worked

Comment: remove the width and the height. If no width and height are declared the svg element will take the width available

Comment: @jessgtrz has your issue been solved?

Answer (score 0):

I made five improvements:

1. Circle's width based on `SkillProficiencyId`.
2. Increased the svg width from `600` to `900`.
3. Text will appear always on the middle of the circle: `text.style("text-anchor", "middle")` did the trick.
4. Text size proportional to circle size;
5. A smartest way to calc circle dx (w/o using arbritary offsets);

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/mayconmesquita/pen/RwWoZbv

**JS Code:**

```
var width = 900;
var height = 400;

// Place your JSON here.
var data = [
  { CategoryName: 'Adaptive Security', SkillProficiencyId: 1 },
  { CategoryName: 'Programmer', SkillProficiencyId: 2 },
  { CategoryName: 'Coffee Lover', SkillProficiencyId: 3 },
  { CategoryName: 'Coffee Roaster', SkillProficiencyId: 4 }
];

function getCircleSize(SkillProficiencyId) {
  var minSize = 60;

  return minSize + (minSize * (SkillProficiencyId * .2));
}

// Make SVG container  
var svgContainer = d3
  .select("body")
  .classed("svg-container", true) 
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

// This function will iterate your data
data.map(function(props, index) {
  /*
    The new CX calc:
    ('circleSize' * 2) will be multiplied by element's index.
    So for 3 elements, cx = 70, 140, 210 ...
    All these values changeable by this vars.
  */
  var circleSize = getCircleSize(props.SkillProficiencyId);
  var cx = (circleSize * 2) * (index); // Here CX is calculated

  var elem = svgContainer.selectAll("div").data(data);

  var elemEnter = elem
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(100, 0)"); // prevent svg crops first circle

  var circles = elemEnter
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", cx)
    .attr("cy", 160)
    .attr("r", circleSize)
    .style("fill", "blue");

  elemEnter
    .append("text")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("dy", 165)
    .attr("dx", cx)
    .text(props.CategoryName)
    .style("font-size", ((circleSize * .2) + index) + "px")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle");
});
```